# What are "store dumps"? I tried googling it, but couldn't really come across anything with the same wording

Tags: vb.net, store

I recently had a question in a piece of homework asking us to explain how "Store dumps" help aid debugging programs, however I don't really know what it means by that term. I tried googling it, but I couldn't come across anything with the same wording

Hoping someone could explain what is meant by the term "store dumps".

Comment: Ask your instructor. We don't know what context that phrase was used, or anything about the material your instructor presented. Ask the person who gave you the question to explain it.

Comment: Can you post some more context around the expression in case you are misreading it?

Comment: @CharlesWood Here was the exact phrasing of the question: "Describe the following aids to debugging programs" of which the term "store dumps" was listed below. Some more context would be we have been coding using visual studio in the language vb.

Comment: Never heard of it.  The fact that Google hasnt heard of it  makes it sound like his made up term for something.

Comment: I've heard of "core dumps", but never in the context of .NET development.

Comment: Not sure that your teacher should be teaching a subject they don't understand. As far as I know, there is no such thing in .net debugging.